# ArgumentError: Unknown key: :presence - error when trying to create a relationship on a relationship table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've made a moderator relationship table to associate users as moderators to groups. When I try and create the mod relationship in the console I get the error:

`ArgumentError: Unknown key: :presence. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :dependent, :primary_key, :inverse_of, :required, :foreign_type, :polymorphic, :touch, :counter_cache`

Here are my files

The table:

```
  def change
create_table :group_mods_relationships do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :group_id

  t.timestamps null: false
end
   add_index :group_mods_relationships, :user_id
   add_index :group_mods_relationships, :group_id
```

end

User model

```
has_many :group_mods_relationships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :group_categories, through: :group_mods_relationships
```

Group model

```
  has_many :users, through: :group_mods_relationships
```

mod relationship model

```
  belongs_to :user, presence: true
  belongs_to :group_category, presence: true

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :group_id, presence: true
```

I run the command `User.find(1).group_mods_relationships.create!(group_id: 1)` which produces the error above.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`belongs_to` doesn't take a `:presence` key, which is for validation, e.g.,

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :group_category
```